# rails has_many :through table don't get saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

I am new to rails so beware of the ugly code. 
I have these models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :games_playeds
 has_many :games, :through => :games_playeds

end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games_playeds
  has_many :users, :through => :games_playeds

end

class GamesPlayed < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :game_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game  

end
```

Game describe a game independent of any user
GamesPlayed describe how users behaved on that game (deaths, current stage, wins, etc)

In each stage of this game the user can choose among several choices, some will get to later stages, some will make him go back. The point is that once a choice is made in one stage I don't allow to choose anything else. 
To implement this I have a   steps  attribute that encode the previous choices like "0:1;1:6;6:2" and so on. This attribute in on the GamesPlayed model.

The pages the user navigates are automatically generated so I don't know their names but I know they are called XX_to_YY. I have a method in my controller that will get them all and do something as ugly as this:

```
      #get the game name, we have several games
      game = Game.find_by_name (params[:game])
      #get the previous and current stage
      from, to = params[:page].to_s.split("_to_")      
      to = to.split(".html")[0]

      played = current_user.games_playeds.find_by_game_id (game.id)

      steps = []
      played.steps.split(";").each {|a| steps << a.split(":").first}
      if steps.include? from
        render :inline => "You already chose for this, go back"
      else        
        played.steps << "#{from}:#{to};"
        played.save
#        pl = current_user.games_playeds.find_by_game_id (game.id)
#        raise pl.steps
        render "games/choosePath/#{game.name}/#{params[:page]}.html"
      end
```

I guess it is a horrible code. I am new to Ruby as well :P

Now, the question:
played.save gives me no errors.

```
#        pl = current_user.games_playeds.find_by_game_id (game.id)
#        raise pl.steps
```

will "print" the correct data but it is not saved in the database! I use sqlitebrowser to visually inspect it and I am sure it is not saved.

BTW, as second question, if someone knows how to get to the association object without that ugly code above very thankful also.

and third and last question:

steps = []
  played.steps.split(";").each {|a| steps << a.split(":").first}

This is also horrible but don't know how to make it better (want to get the aa and bb from "aa:cc;bb:dd;" I don't know what is aa and bb, it can be numbers or words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to raise an exception when `save` fails, call `save!`; otherwise if you continue to use `save` you should check the returned boolean to see if the save was successful.

A `false` return value will indicate that validations have failed. The details of the failures will be in the error information on the model.

---

About getting the association in a better way: there is probably something you could do with scopes or even just by writing a method to encapsulate what you are trying to do.

---

With regard to decoding the steps, you could use `inject` instead of `each` but it would still be quite logic heavy. I would suggest encapsulating it in a method with a descriptive name, like `decode_steps` or similar.

Comment: Try changing `played.steps << "#{from}:#{to};"` to `played.steps = played.steps + "#{from}:#{to};"` just to check if it makes a difference. You could also try recreating this in the rails console to see if you can shed any more light on why the save is not happening.

Comment: I don't know why but changing to played.steps = played.steps + "#{from}:#{to};" made it work!

Comment: My thinking was that ActiveRecord did not notice the change to `played.steps` when using `<<` and so didn't think the object had changed. This may be due to `<<` mutating the existing String object where as adding two Strings makes a new String object that gets assigned into `played.steps`. You can probably just replace `<<` with `+=`.